# mysql sql file import dump with apostrophes

Tags: mysql, command-line

I have a SQL database dump which is 8mb and I am trying to import via the commandline with the below code:

```
mysql -uroot -p dbname < dbnamedump.sql
```

I only have one copy of this file and can not export it again from the database and I am getting the below errors:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 29675: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Dining Room', '-33.922318', '18.417137', '133 Bree Street', '', 'Cape Town', '' at line 5
```

I realise this is an issue with apostrophes but not sure how to work around this and get the data in, I would normally replace ' with \'

Any thoughts please?

Thanks

John.

Comment: Please post the insert line.

Comment: you can split on commas and replace the quotes with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an embedded quote. One of your string values has a quote inside it.
This guy:

```
's Dining Room
```

You need to double the quotes when generating the SQL.

Comment: Thanks for reply, trouble is I only have the SQL file and I dont have access to the server to redo export.

Comment: Yeah sorted it thanks.  It only occured a few times so manually did it thanks.